# Output caching & substitution in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

Is the approach for implementing substitution caching in MVC 3 contained in [this page](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/07/01/Extending-ASPNET-MVC-OutputCache-ActionFilterAttribute-Adding-substitution.aspx) still valid? It was written in 2008 and MVC has changed dramatically since then so I'm not sure if there's a more current implementation of this.

Obviously the concept of a view code-behind isn't used anymore, but I'm referring more to the specifics of implementing the caching substitution itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle for substitution caching will be still same in MVC3, but MVC3 RC is adding support for the partial caching (exactly opposite way than substitution, but it can solve your issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about new output caching features in MVC 3 here: http://aspalliance.com/2017_Announcing_the_ASPNET_MVC_3_Release_Candidate_.5

Answer (score 0):

Output cache substitution was possible in MVC 1 but it has been removed since then. However, you can use it via [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth).